# How to Create ASP.Net Chart Control from Database using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I am working on a web app(Asp.Net) and need to draw a chart which is using data from database.
In debug mode, I can retrieve data from database but when try to add chart

chart proporties-> dataSourceId -> SqlDataSource..
connectionstring is ok

Then I get this

> The data provide 'FirebirdSql.Data.Firebird.Client' could not be found in the system configuration. unable to find the requested .NetFramework Data Provider. it may not be installed.

Why I am getting this and how to fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most probably to do with the version of Firebird. Check your machine.config file for these lines:

Wrong:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" type="System.Data.Common.DbProviderConfigurationHandler, System.Data, Version=2.6.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
</configSections>
```

What it should be:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="firebirdsql.data.firebirdclient" type="System.Data.Common.DbProviderConfigurationHandler, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
</configSections>
```

Your machine.config file can be found at these locations (x86 or x64):

**32-bit**

```
x:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\[version]\config\machine.config
```

**64-bit**

```
x:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\[version]\config\machine.config
```

I think you only need to edit the 32 bit version of the machine.config file as VS 2010 is 32-bit only I believe.

Try these things first and hopefully you'll find a fix!

EDIT; try reinstalling Firebird, download the latest version and uninstall all instances of Firebird from your computer beforehand

http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-provider/

Comment: actually you were right :) i dont know I copyed it where but it was like that

    <section name="**firebirsql**.data.firebirdclient" type="System.Data.Common.DbProviderConfigurationHandler, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
not like that
    <section name="firebirdsql.data.firebirdclient" type="System.Data.Common.DbProviderConfigurationHandler, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" /> thanks ;)